# jQuery countdown timer

Tags: php, jquery

I am using:

```
 $(function () {
    endAuction = new Date(
        data.year,
        data.month,
        data.day,
        data.hour,
        data.minute,
        data.second
    );
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('destroy')
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
        until: endAuction,
        format: 'DHMS',
        onExpiry: endAuctionReload
        //,onTick: highlightLast5
    });
 });
```

to create a countdown timer from a time sent by an ajax call (PHP file) however this wont work if a user changes their local clock. Is there a way to force the server time as opposed to the local time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What countdown plugin are you using? Check the documentation. If it's [this one](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html), there is a `serverSync` option that does the following:

> Synchronise the client's time with that of the server by providing a function that returns the current server date and time. This date and time should take into account the server's timezone and any difference between that time and the client's is applied to the countdown when it is started or changed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that and yes that is the plugin I am using however, it will still change the end time if I change my local clock. I have to refresh the page for it to correct the time. Do you know of a way to check every 10 or 20 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

In simple PHP, generate it to JS:

```
endAuction = new Date(
        <?php echo date('y').',' ......... ?>
    );
```

Remeber to don't rely on javascript logic when securtiy issues are important like end of auction or sth. Use it only to show something.

And remebmer to set default timezone in PHP